# How to Google search "filetype:x" union "filetype:y"?

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to do a search for all torrent files and pdf files related to "secrets of the javascript ninja".

I can do them individually as shown:

> **"secrets of the javascript ninja" filetype:pdf** [(~6560 results)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22secrets+of+the+javascript+ninja%22+filetype%3Atorrent)
>
> **"secrets of the javascript ninja" filetype:torrent** [(~146 results)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22secrets+of+the+javascript+ninja%22+filetype%3Atorrent)

But how do we *concatenate* the results? In essense, I would like Google to display the union of the above two searches.

I've tried ["secrets of the javascript ninja" filetype:(torrent or pdf)](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=%22secrets%20of%20the%20javascript%20ninja%22%20filetype%3a%28torrent%20or%20pdf%29) but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to do union searches on Google?

Answer (score 2):

From the little casting about I've done, it looks like you need to use `OR` between the `filetype:` operator if you want multiple filetypes.

```
"secrets of the javascript ninja" filetype:pdf OR filetype:torrent
```

My quick tests seem to jive. It's a little hard to verify, because there are so many more PDF results than Torrent results (for this particular case, at least).

Comment: I also did some casting around on this, and Google's performance seems odd.    If I tred   "secrets of the javascript ninja" filetype:pdf or filetype:torrent - I got no results.   Ditto    "secrets of the javascript ninja" filetype:pdf OR  filetype:torrent     (ie two spaces after an UpperCase OR).

Comment: You need to uppercase that "OR" or Google considers it part of the search string.

Comment: @AlE., No idea why, but it Doesn't work. Try this: `"Fundamentals of Telecommunication Networks" filetype:pdf OR filetype:torrent`. Does it work for you?

Comment: Hard to say. I only get one torrent result when I search for that.